# Finding the maximum of multiple values in 2 dataframe columns Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple question.

I have a dataframe that has values that look like these:

```
Unit     Load     Value
1        3        4
2        3        3.2
3        2        4.1
1        5        3.4
2        4        3.8
3        4        6.1
.
.
```

I want to find the maximum values of all `Units` for the column `Value`.

Ie: in this example `Unit 1` has a max of `4` and `Unit 2` has a max of `3.8`....etc....

What's the easiest way of doing this? (Load values don't matter)

Comment: df.groupby('Unit').Value.max()

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('Unit').Value.max()
```